# Create new column with a specific range of values

Tags: r, date-range

I'm trying to create a new column with the range of numbers from 0-40 in the total impressions column. [image]

I'm trying to utilize the ifelse function, if that pertains here.
This is what I have so far:

`group1 <-rocketfuel[rocketfuel$total_impr==<-ifelse(rocketfuel$total_imp<=40, rocketfuel$tot_impr ]`

The goal is to break up the customers into 6 group based on number of impressions, so group 1 will be 0-40 impressions, group 2 will be 41-80 impressions and so on.

Update: Utilizing one of the solutions given below, which is almost exactly what I'm looking for

```
rocketfuel$group1 <- ifelse(rocketfuel$tot_impr<=40,1,NA)
```

And getting this as a result [image]

Instead of the group1 column spitting out the #1, I want it to spit out #21, is that possible?

Figured it out!

Comment: can you show the expected output.  Also, `ifelse` needs 3 parameters. THe closing `)` is not there

Comment: What does `==<-` do in your attempt?

Comment: I don't think it's doing anything for me lol, but normally when I try to separate out data I can do something like this group1 <-rocketfuel[rocketfuel$total_impr==40, ] which separates all the data that has 40 total impressions

Comment: @helpneededthankyou can you update your post with the expected output

Comment: Got it, just added it @akrun thank you!

Comment: I don't see any change in the table column values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to subset the values of users who had fewer than 40 impressions or are you trying to create a group of users?
Also, make sure your column names are consistent in the call (e.g. "total_imp" vs "total_impr").

```
rocketfuel <- data.frame(user_id=c(1069124,1119715,1144181,1435133,1015700),
    test=rep(1,5),
    converted=rep(0,5), 
    tot_impr=c(130,93,21,355,276),
    mode_impr_day=c(1,2,2,2,5), 
    mode_impr_hour=c(20,22,18,10,14))
```

If you are trying to create a group, just add it as its own variable(column). Using ifelse() is similar to excel, you can do something like this

`rocketfuel$group_lt_40 <- ifelse(rocketfuel$total_impr<=40,1,NA)`

if you're trying to create a column of impressions under 40, you can still use ifelse() and keep the original value of impressions try:

`rocketfuel$group_lt_40_impr <-ifelse(rocketfuel$total_impr<=40,rocketfuel$total_impr,NA)`

Comment: This is great, thanks for figuring out what I'm looking for! For the first code you wrote down, where you wrote the number 1, what if I wanted to keep the impressions the same still, e.g. if the tot_impr column said 29 impressions, then the new group column still spits out 29

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(`0-40` = as.logical(ifelse(tot_impr>=0 & tot_impr<=40, TRUE, FALSE)))
```

Output:

```
  user_id.s  test converted tot_impr mode_impr_day mode_impr_hour `0-40`
      <int> <int>     <int>    <int>         <int>          <int> <lgl> 
1   1069124     1         0      130             1             20 FALSE 
2   1119715     1         0       93             2             22 FALSE 
3   1144181     1         0       21             2             18 TRUE  
4   1435133     1         0      355             2             10 FALSE 
5   1015700     1         0      276             5             14 FALSE
```

data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~user_id.s, ~test, ~converted, ~tot_impr, ~mode_impr_day, ~mode_impr_hour,
    1069124L,    1L,         0L,      130L,             1L,             20L,
    1119715L,    1L,         0L,       93L,             2L,             22L,
    1144181L,    1L,         0L,       21L,             2L,             18L,
    1435133L,    1L,         0L,      355L,             2L,             10L,
    1015700L,    1L,         0L,      276L,             5L,             14L
  )
```